# Is there any way to find out my admin name?

Tags: macos, administrator

I'm a teenager who is into gaming. I've had a PS4 since last Christmas and pretty much haven't stopped playing it ever since. However, I've recently started to play on my Mac (and by recently I mean today) again, but everything I try to install requires an "Administrator Name and Password" which I understand and I used to remember. Seeing as I haven't used my Mac since last year it must be understandable how I've forgotten it. Every time I type my account name (located at the top right of my screen) and my login password it isn't correct.

I must have deleted my original account and I can't remember the name for it. Is there any way I will be able to find out?

Answer (score 1):

If you end up needing to make a new admin account, there are several threads here covering that. I'd start with this one:

- [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac)

You can open the system preferences and look over all the users and groups. That way you can determine if you have the ability to recover a current admin or need to start with another and just go forward.