# User account no longer in ‘admin’, how to recover?

Tags: macos, user-account, administrator

After a recent OS X update (currently Sierra, 10.12.3) the normal user on this machine is no longer in the `admin` group.

I don't know what caused the account to be removed from that group; how can I get it back?

---

Advice found via [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac) suggests booting to Single-User mode, and using the `dscl` command:

```
dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership username
```

This fails immediately:

```
Could not read path: path = /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist, error = 2: No such file or directory
```

and no change in groups occurs. Apparently I can't expect `dscl` to work in Single-User mode.

So what should I do, to re-add the username to the `admin` group?

Comment: None of the answers mention a `dscl ..` command - a link in a comment does though. You have to add some details (i.e. what have you done so far and what are you trying to do) to your question.

Comment: Why don’t you follow this answer to remove the .AppleSetupDone file. Easy-peasy make a new admin then r-grant admin as needed.

Answer (score 5):

After starting to Single User Mode enter:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

Launch opendirectoryd:

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
```

Then enter (replacing *username* with the real user name):

```
dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership username
```

You will get an error "...com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist doesn't exit anymore ..." - ignore it! Your user should still get promoted to an admin user.

Enter `exit` to boot to the GUI.

Comment: This worked for me even though both `launchctl` and `dscl` spewed some errors.

Comment: Yikes. Recovery has a way of resetting the passwords so long as disk isn't encrypted, and you know the firmware password if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

What's easiest is to add a new admin account. To do this:

**1. Boot into single user mode**

After power on, immediately press and hold <kbd>Command-S</kbd>

your system will boot showing a lot more details, and drop you on a shell prompt.

NOTE: if your system has a firmware password this will fail. You need to first remove that password temporarily. See here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4347468

**2. Make the filesystem writable**

issue the command `mount -uw /`

**3. Remove the file indicating the system has been setup previously**

issue the command `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

**4. Let the boot continue**

press <kbd>Control-D</kbd> or type `reboot` to make the system continue the boot and/or reboot (which doesn't matter)

**5. Add a new temporary user account in the GUI**

The system now boots and thinks it's unconfigured and will ask in a graphical user interface the details to create a new admin account, just like it did when it was new out of the box. Make sure it's a **NEW** account. And don't transfer data or anything like that.

It will also log you in as that user

**6. fix your old account**
You can now make changes to the original user and give it admin rights again etc.

**7. remove temp admin account**
Log out en log in with your fixed account and remove the temporarily created admin account.

**More info:**

Please see here as well: [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac/164332#comment413321_164332)