# Stopping "wants to make changes" password prompts on secondary account when performing admin tasks

Tags: macos, password, user-account, administrator

I have a secondary user account that I use for work. Both my primary account and this one are set to Admin.

When installing software updates (and in other instances that require higher privileges) while logged in on my secondary account, macOS will ask me for my secondary account's password.

This does not happen on my primary account, and I wish for it to stop happening on my secondary account too.

How can I make macOS stop asking for my secondary account's password every time a change needs to be made?

Answer (score 1):

You need one admin account for  his operation. If You don’t have one:

- [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac)

Stopping the prompt is going to be hard, so eithe you’ll want to make your current account an admin and use that password for this or use another admin user/password when prompted. You  do not have to log out of your current standard user, just that you have to use an admin with it’s admin password