# Finder can't authenticate even though I am the admin

Tags: macos, mac, unlock, administrator

I am trying to authenticate but it seems that my approach is not working. I am logged into the administrator account, so I obviously know the admin password, but I can't authenticate in Finder or any other place that requires unlock.
I am running the latest macOS High Sierra.

[image]

This is a proof that I am the Admin.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What message does it give on failed authentication?

Comment: You have not Admin account your profile is a standard account. Have you at your login screen another user profile with admin privileges? Are you able to enable the checkbox named **Allow user to administer this computer** ?

Comment: no its not possible to check that check box at all, its need to be unlocked to do so and when i try the it says the password is incorrect

Comment: @JMY1000 it doesn't give an message its just a window that perform a quick shake animation

Comment: @dante12 is correct. The screenshot you're showing us actually confirms the opposite of what you're saying, namely that the account you're logged into is actually a *Standard* account, and that it's also not allowed to administer the computer. More specifically, below the name Ayoub in the lefthand pane is the word 'Standard'. And, as Dante12 says, the necessary checkbox is not ticked.

Comment: @Monomeeth yeah you're right i just came to realize that ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the list of accounts, it appears to be that you're not an admin and there is no admin account on your computer. [You'll need to create an admin account by running Setup Assistant again.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac)

> 1. Boot into Single User Mode <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.
> 2. Mount the drive by typing `/sbin/mount -uw /` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 3. Remove the Apple Setup Done file by typing `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 4. Reboot by typing `reboot` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 5. Complete the setup process, creating a new admin account.

Comment: i love this answer, it worked perfectly in my case ,, thanks man, you just saved me countless hours

Comment: Glad I could help :) Credit to grgarside for the original answer.