# How to login again in Users and Groups again and also how to gain sudo access which lost privilege

Tags: terminal, mac, single-user

> macOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

How to login again in Users and Groups
Also before with old username, I could access sudo. How to gain back sudo access.
I went into **Users and Groups** -->
Unlocked successfully -->
**Changed Account Name** -->
Restarted mac.

- tried to get `sudo` access to one of the hidden files.     got error
  `[myname] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`
- cant logo in my **Users and Groups** again

I have also tried `su -`, `vi /etc/sudoers`, `sudo -v`, `sudo dscl` .

```
-merge /Groups/admin GroupMembership <username>
Password:
<username> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

[Also tired](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310248/cannot-unlock-users-groups-settings)

```
dscl . -append /groups/admin GroupMembership USERNAME
<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)
```

ok just found out i have two users

```
 su OLACCOUNTNAME
    bash-3.2$ sudo dscl / -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership OLACCOUNTNAME
    OLACCOUNTNAME is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
dscl . -read /groups/admin GroupMembership
GroupMembership: root


su NEWACCOUNTNAME
Password:
su: Sorry
```

*It never asked me to change password or add a new one for this user.

```
su OLDACCOUNTNAME
id -a
uid=501(OLDACCOUNTNAME) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),100(_lpoperator)

dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'
daemon
blindshot
nobody
root
```

Comment: Also, did you rename the only Admin user on your system? If you run `id -a` is the user still part of the `admin` group?

Comment: yes `id -a` it shows the old account name in `uid=501(blindshot) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),100(_lpoperator)`

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac. This should allow you to create a new admin user and get access again. If you need help in cleaning up the `blindshot` account, please ask a new question for this.