# Renaming user failed, lost admin rights

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I wanted to change the name of my user as well as its home directory. Looking for a way to do this, I stumbled upon [this support document](https://support.apple.com/hr-hr/HT201548).

I did everything as described there, but since I restarted the computer, all that happened is, that I'm not an admin anymore.

I can't *unlock* anything under *System Preferences > Users & Groups*, as well as I'm unable to edit */etc/sudoers/*

What went wrong?
*whoami* still shows my previous username..

How can I fix this mess? Am I screwed now?

macOS 10.13.4 btw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac)

> 1. Boot into Single User Mode: Start/restart your Mac. As soon as you hear the startup tone, press and hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
>    until you see a black screen with white lettering. (If you end up back
>    on the login screen after a flash of the black screen with white
>    lettering, enter your password and it will return to the black
>    screen.)
> 2. Mount the drive by typing `/sbin/mount -uw /` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 3. Remove the Apple Setup Done file by typing  `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 4. Reboot by typing `reboot` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
> 5. Complete the setup process, creating a new admin account.

This should allow you to create a new admin user.

Comment: Starting in macOS Catalina (10.15), macOS uses a [split volume format](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367158), which complicates this procedure. Change the `mount` command to `mount -uw /System/Volumes/Data`, and the `rm` command to `rm /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone`. Also, some newer Macs disallow Single-User mode, so you have to use Recovery mode (with different commands) instead (see my comments at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331)).

Answer (score -1):

Another way is:

First write the command on terminal:

```
pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/sudo
```

After that follow the steps below:

1. Restart the OSX with holding down keys <kbd>Cmd-S</kbd>
2. Choose in the menu "Utilities" the option "Terminal"
3. Force check the file with command: `/sbin/fsck/ -fy`
4. Mount the file system with command: `/sbin/mount -uw /`
5. Change the permission on sudo: `chmod 4511 /usr/bin/sudo`
6. Now reboot the computer with command: `reboot`

Comment: How does this recreate the admin account? What is the purpose of running `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/sudo`?