# Screwed up administrative name on sudo when trying to change usernames

Tags: terminal, password, permission, sudo

Disclaimer: I am NOT at all fluent in coding or its jargon, so bear with me.

I recently downloaded a software and wanted to remove it. I tried to do it via sudo on the MacBook terminal. I was trying to follow the advice from this website: http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/06/add-user-sudoers-file-mac/

Incidentally, I literally typed "username" instead of my actual username for my actual account. Now I can't even touch sudo or do anything with it.

I try to type `visudo` and it says "permission denied." I try to type `sudoer` and it doesn't give me the prompt to type the password like it did before and it doesn't respond to any input I place in, whether it is spam or a helpless `help` command.

I followed the advice [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323495/renaming-user-failed-lost-admin-rights) and it still doesn't work. Now I have two admin accounts. I am beyond lost now as to how to revert my sudo thing.

Edit: I ran the code `ls -l /etc/sudoers` and the results were `-r--r-----  1 root  wheel  2306 May  7 02:21 /etc/sudoers`

Inputed `cat /etc/sudoers` command. Embarrassing username from middle school inbound:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you log in with the newly created admin account and run `sudo echo Hello` from there?

Comment: I entered it and nothing happens. It doesn't give any response. I keep typing enter and it just keeps entering with no text.

Comment: The change you describe in your question shouldn't have had any negative effects at all, it just would have allowed a non-existing user to use `sudo`. So either something else got changed (maybe without you noticing it), or you did something else outside of `visudo`as well.

Comment: Can you please run `ls -l /etc/sudoers` and *edit* the result into the question? Then boot into single user mode again, run `cat /etc/sudoers > /Users/Shared/s; chmod 666 /Users/Shared/s`, then reboot as usual and add the content of `/Users/Shared/s` to the question as well?

Comment: I figured given me literally adding "username" when I should've put in my actual username has actually created a non-existing user to use the sudo command. I even made another account on my mac titled "username" to hopefully reaccess visudo, but it didn't work... My educated guess from my lack of programming experience is that I think at this point it's about working to revert this and giving it back to my actual admin account.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. You need to run `/sbin/fsck -fy` and `/sbin/mount -uw /` first after booting to Single User Mode, afterwards the `cat` part will work.

Comment: Good thinking about the `username` account, this *should* have worked. So I still think something else is interfering here as well.

Comment: Is there any way to see what username I typed in for the `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` sudo admin part?

Comment: Well, if you *replaced* the `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` (instead of adding an additonal one) this might explain what you are seeing. To see the content please do as indicated above (single user, run fsck and mount, cat file, reboot, add file to question)

Comment: But to make it easier: Just run `cat /etc/sudoers` after booting to single user, and post the picture. I think we can fix it directly there.

Comment: Alright, updated. However, my username stated above already corresponds to an existing user account that's just standard and doesn't have and administrative powers. I actually just updated all my accounts now to have administrative powers and no sudo commands work still.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Reboot into Single User mode
- Run `/sbin/fsck -fy`
- Run `/sbin/mount -uw /`
- Run `vi /etc/sudoers` (assuming you know `vi`, otherwise use `nano`)
- In the "User privilege specification" part replace `%awesomechris` with `%admin` (the `%` is important)
- Save and reboot

PS: The `%` identicates a user *group*, so creating a new user didn't help (even if you would have named it `awesomechris` instead of `username`)

PPS: Once everything is fixed, remove Admin rights from users who don't need it (make sure at least one is left). Then log in with an admin user, run `sudo WHATEVER-IS-NEEDED-TO-REMOVE-YOUR-SOFTWARE` and enter the password of the same admin user to confirm).

Comment: I have been up since 1AM and now it's 5AM and the birds are chirping. You did it. You're truly the best I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @ChrisLi You're welcome. When using `visudo` it's usually better to *add* new stuff instead of replacing existing entries. This significantly reduces the risk of locking oneself out.