# upgrading MacOS to Catalina error "opt" file cannot be copied

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, catalina

Attempted upgrade from El Capitan to Catalina, upgrade stalled with error "opt" file cannot be copied. Tried restarting 3 times.

Error repeated. Booted into Recovery mode using Command R. Tried to recover from pre upgrade backup received error cannot backup from non APFS version.

Looked at disk utility have Mac HD, Mac HD Data, MacOS Base volumes all listing 10.15. now stumped at what to try next. Am IT savvy but spent much time learning enough about my Macs but still prefer them to Windows OS.

Suggestions for what to try next.

MacOS Utilities offers reinstall MacOS and I think it will just try Catalina again.

Went into terminal to try to find opt but I'm useless in terminal.
I can see -bash-3.2# prompt and Library and .forward in directory. All this trouble when I need to takean online exam and needed to upgrade to do it. Explains why I'm slow to update stuff because it never goes smooth.

Comment: Do you have MacPorts installed? MacPorts puts all its files into the `/opt` directory.

Comment: I didn't think I installed macports but I have done some messing about with Brew and Java editors. I found opt directory. When I did cd / then ls and it has .vol etc opt Applications tmp usr

Comment: Can I remove the directory "opt" it's empty or write something in it that's harmless so Catalina has something to copy?

Comment: A similar problem was reported [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250716928) but the resolution is unclear (to me). If the folder is empty then you can remove it with `sudo rmdir /opt`.  – But I do not know what the exact problem is. Some files/directories are moved to a new location during the Catalina install, because of the new separation into read-only system volume and read-write user space (compare https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367159/30895). But I have no idea why `/opt` is a problem.