# Lost admin privileges on iMac

Tags: time-machine, permission, administrator

It happened after changing admin name following migration to new Mac Air. I've tried various suggested fixes calling for Single User Mode, then `mount-uw/` and `rm /var/db/`. AppleSetUp, also going to Disk Utility and following suggestion to mount, etc. Nothing works. Every time I run a command I get `no such file or directory`, which I can only assume is why these fixes aren't working. Two questions:
1.Is there another step to the usual fixes that I need to be taking to avoid "no such file..."?
2. If all else fails, if I were to back up the system from Time Machine (pre-problem causing event), will my old admin privileges (name, password) be restored and things will be as they were, say, two weeks ago?
(High Sierra 10.13.6 if that matters)

Comment: Starting in macOS Catalina (10.15), macOS uses a [split volume format](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367158), which requires changes to the various procedures. I've added comments to several out-of-date answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331); see if the procedures there (modified per my comments) work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It’s going to be hard to offer blanket advice since if your hardware has failed, your backup is suspect, no amount of correct process will help. This would be a data recovery project which is very different than trying to recover from a lost password, admin database corruption.

1. Reinstalling the current OS from recovery should fix the machine enough to follow this guide to reset the password. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211672
2. If you know your backup is good, erase the Mac and then migrate back. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/erase-and-reinstall-macos-mh27903/mac

If you ask a follow on question making notes which parts of the password reset process you chose and what step was the last you could complete, we might be able to offer a process change in case you missed a step or there’s an undocumented fix, but there are a ton of steps in the reset process, hard to guess where your case diverged from the expected path...