# What is morphunassetsupdaterd?

Tags: launchd

I haven't noticed this process earlier.

```
Process:         morphunassetsupdaterd [2684]
Path:            /usr/libexec/morphunassetsupdaterd
Load Address:    0x105960000
Identifier:      morphunassetsupdaterd
Version:         100.4
Code Type:       X86-64
Platform:        macOS
Parent Process:  launchd [1]
OS Version:      macOS 11.6.1 (20G224)
```

Is it legit process or malware?

Comment: The `/usr/libexec/` directory is on the [sealed (read-only) system volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/whats-system-volumes-data), so unless you've disabled the OS's built-in integrity protection, everything in there is from Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by inspecting the plaintext strings in the binary, it's easy to tell that `morphunassetsupdaterd` is a **[daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing))** that is used by **Siri** to download updates to language assets, or ***morphuns***  (according to the internal terminology used at least in this code)

Here's some selected output from `strings /usr/libexec/morphunassetsupdaterd`:

```
updateAssetsForLanguages:
removeAssetsForLanguages:
logLanguageList:languages:
singleShotUpdateForLanguages:
singleShotRemoveForLanguages:
getAllLanguagePaths
getCurrentLanguages
updateCatalogue:
updateAssetForLanguage:error:
purgeAssetsForLanguage:error:
startCatalogDownload:options:then:
isUpdateNeededForLanguage:neededAsset:uneededAssets:error:
spaceCheck:
startDownload:then:
purgeSync
purgeResultToString:
queryInstalledAssetIds
isMorphunOnDisk
isMorphunInstalled
morphunCompareByVersion:
morphunMasteredVersion
purgeAllAssets
morphunContentVersion
morphunLanguage
morphunPath
morphunModelDir
morphunDescription
isMorphunDownloading
morphunModelPath
init:removeLanguages:
Some language's assets were not updated: %@
All language assets were updated successfully.
Languages to update: %@
No languages were asked to be updated
Languages to remove: %@
No languages were asked to be removed
+[MorphunAssetsUpdaterDaemon convertXPCStringArrayToNSArray:]
/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Morphun/Morphun-61/morphunassetsupdaterd/Daemon/MorphunAssetsUpdaterDaemon.m
com.apple.private.siri-morphunassetsupdaterd
com.apple.siri.morphunassetsupdaterd
com.apple.MobileAsset.MorphunData
MorphunAssetsUpdaterDaemon
Found asset for language "%@": "%s"
Downloading assets catalogue for %@
Assets catalogue failed to download: %@ (%ld)
Successfully downloaded assets catalogue.
Language "%@" needs update? %s
Asset download progress: %lld of %lld
Asset requires %lld bytes, starting download...
Asset download failed: %@ (%ld)
Asset for language "%@" updated. %lu previous assets need to be purged.
Purging old asset failed: %@ (%ld)
Not enough space to download asset, size=%lld
Installed assets query failed: %@ (%ld)
Warning: Asset query results are empty
Purging asset failed: %@ (%ld)
Found asset for language "%@"
MorphunAssetsUpdaterDaemon
MorphunAssetsClient
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know this is part of Siri. It is surprising to see that daemon is running while Siri is not enabled in settings. A bit wasteful from the resource utilization perspective but keeps the Siri service readiness up to date.