# I don't have administrator account anymore - macOS 10.13.4

Tags: high-sierra, security, administrator

I tried the answers on the similar previous question but nothing worked.
Obviously Apple removed the critical file .AppleSetupDone in the last Security Update.
Is there anybody who could help getting my administrator account back?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can you please [edit] your question to add a reference to the answers you already tried but didn't work?  We don't know what you tried and this will prevent us from suggesting those same answers again.

Comment: Rather than say you tried other answers, please show your detailed work. The process of documenting your situation allows someone to help and also keeps the chance of duplicate questions with the same answer from proliferating.

Answer (score 1):

The removal of file **.AppleSetupDone** to trigger Setup Assistant is still here and fully functional in High Sierra, even in the latest 10.13.5 Beta. You can remove this file either in Single User mode or in Terminal when booted in Recovery Partition.

Another way to restore your admin account is to boot in Recovery Partition, starting Terminal and using the **resetpassword** command to launch the helper app (see attached screenshot).

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. Would you consider editing it into the selected answer on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331 to let everyone know that answer and the reset tool work on high Sierra?

Comment: @bmike I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. There are three answers, which do you suggest I supplant?

Comment: I would tack it on the end of this one, personally. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/164332/5472 You could also just make your answer there stand alone. Just suggestions, though. Only do this if it makes sense to you.

Comment: @bmike I expanded and submitted https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/324521/191531 as you suggested.