# Wallpaper lock after mac restarting

Tags: login, macos

I recently restarted my mac and after login i am locked in a wallpaper.

[image]

This is a picture after i logged in.

If you know how i can make it work again you would save me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a whole article what to do when a restart doesn’t work. Which of these steps fails you?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Once you start in safe mode, you’ll know if you need to reinstall or just make Some changes to the apps you start when the graphical boot portion is running.

Another tool would be to make a new user to test:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204443

You need a functioning admin account to follow Apple’s steps above and I’ll assume you can’t log in as another user. Here’s a “trick” or procedure to make a new admin account.

- [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac/164332#164332)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I started my mac in safe mode and the probleme still happen. There is no help for that in the link you send me.

Comment: I’ll edit next steps. @JeremyM.