# Cant boot to SUM macbook pro 2018

Tags: password, restart

Im trying to reset the forgotten admin password but while pressing command+s its just shows white text on screen and immediately heads to apple logo and login screen,

Comment: Best guess, secure boot is enabled - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364310/no-administrator-was-found-in-startup-security-utility

Comment: how to check?Because I check for firmware password and i doesnt have one?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/HT208198