How to re-install macOS on Mac Mini 2018 where Internet Recovery fails and USB boot is forbidden?
I need to re-intall macOS Catalina on my Mac Mini 2018. SSD was wiped out.
Trial 1: Internet Recovery (Alt + Shift + Cmd + R or Alt + R)
Disclaimer: I have a Gigabit Internet connection, without any known issues.
All looks good until: macOS could not be installed on your computer

Running Apple Diagnostic (obviously?) ends up in: No issues found.

Rebooting and retrying the installation then always (no matter how many times I try) leads to: macOS could not be installed on your computer

Trial 2: USB key
From another Mac, I downloaded Catalina and made a USB key:
softwareupdate -d --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.15.6
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/UNTITLED

But, trying to reboot on the USB key: Security settings do not allow this Mac to use an external startup disk.

And when trying to change the said setting: No administrator was found.

Trial 3: dd
Yes, I even tried from the terminal to dump the USB installation key into the SSD, hoping it would reboot on it ... but no, it ignores the SSD and restarts instead on the Internet Recovery mode.
So I tried restoring a dump of a full Monterey hard drive, from another working Mac. The Mac Mini boots on Recovery Mode, a User / Password is requested and accepted (maybe due to the fact that the Monterey drive is encrypted?). I then try a recovery installation of Monterey but: The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.BuildInfo.preflight.error error21.)

I still try to unlock USB port, as the login / password was already asked and accepted, but: The current RecoveryOS has no access to security settings.

With nothing left to lose, I wipe out the SSD with Disk Utility, and retry the Monterey recovery installation. I accept the software license agreement, and then: An error occurred loading the update.

Trial 4: Apple Time Machine
I did a Time Machine backup from the other Mac (macOS Monterey) to an external hard drive. The Time Machine hard drive is well recognized on the Mac Mini, but: No macOS system backups were found.

I guess Apple Time Machine backs up only the Data partition from Monterey, not the OS partition ...
So, I tried with a Time Machine backup of High Sierra (without separate Data partition): You can't restore this backup because this Mac does not support booting from HFS.

Trial 5: Disk Utility Backup / Restore Image
I backed up the Monterey full drive as a dmg image from the other Mac, and tried to restore it on the Mac Mini SSD. I select the image file, but the "Restore" button is completely unresponsive: I can only click "Cancel".
I feel trapped in an Apple loop: I cannot allow booting on USB because the disk is clean without any administrator account, and I cannot create an administrator account because I cannot install macOS from an USB key.
Thank you in advance for any suggestion.
P.S.: SSD is soldered, so no option here to install from a different computer.

Hi. Can you boot into recovery mode and access Terminal under "Utilities" ? Also, do you know if the disk is encrypted ?

Yes, I can access Terminal in Recovery Mode, that is how I tried dd.
No, the disk is not encrypted.

Okay, follow this link, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364310/no-administrator-was-found-in-startup-security-utility. The instructions by William Tong that begin under "8 Answers" sound like they work if you have access to another working Mac.

Thank you, but unless I am mistaken, you have to be able to plug out and back your main SSD, which is not possible for a Mac Mini 2018 where the SSD is soldered?
Edit: my second Mac is a MacBook Air 2015 with Monterey, with a proprietary SSD connector.

No, he says you use the other Mac to make a working OS (Catalina in your case) on an external SSD then connect it to your 'Macbrick' and then use recovery mode/Disk Utility/Restore function to copy the new working external drive contents to your internal SSD....then resart again in Recovery mode and try to do the fresh install again now that your internal drive has a new/restored OS on it.

...of course you could also use an external HDD instead of an external SSD

...and you may do well to try this using your own Mac in Recovery mode and selecting the external drive to make the initial working OS

Erasing the entire device on a T2 or M-series Mac will turn it into a brick.
You will need to connect it to another Mac and run the Apple Configurator app to "revive" and restore it.
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/apple-configurator-mac/apdebea5be51/mac

Thank you for the suggestion. Does reviving or restoring the firmware switch off USB boot security?

@MaguyIB No, it's independent of that. You can configure other Macs in this way regardless of the boot security settings.
