# stuck with name and new and enter password prompt

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina

I reinstalled Catalina and everything works just fine with installation. but I am stuck at here and the setup assistant doesn't show up after the installation. 
I tried I Cloud account and I tried also the old user password
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal. This is a macOS setting that some users prefer because it might provide more security. Do you remember the Username of your user when you were on Mojave (Or High Sierra)? If so, that is your username in the "Name" field. Password is the password to that user.

**If you don't remember your creds:**
If you don't remember your login information, you can try using macOS Recovery to find out. First, boot macOS Recovery by restarting and pressing Command + R. Next, access the Terminal. If you had your disk encrypted, then first, you would need to type `diskutil unlockVolume diskID` and type the password of the disk. Then, type `diskutil mount diskID`. Then, you can do `cd /Volumes/VolName/Users` and `ls`. This will show you all users on the Mac.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks I needed to delete. Applesetupdone to get the setupassistant again becuaee there were no any admin. But now I am afraid if that means the I have 2 os on my Mac

Comment: You can check by seeing if there are 2 Macintosh HDs. Also, for future issues, you can also try using ```sudo dscl . -create``` from Single User Mode to create a new user.

Comment: I created a user with assistant manager. But you mean checking dublicate of HD in disk utility?

Comment: Well actually, having two instances of macOS means that you have two disks with one instance each. That might tell you if you have two instances of macOS. The ```sudo dscl . -create``` was a suggestion should you run into the problem again.

Comment: I just have one Mac HD so I think I have one Mac OS because I just reinstalled Mac OS. And reinstalling Mac OS doesn't dublicate

Comment: Yes I know but above you said "But now I am afraid if that means the I have 2 os on my Mac". I thought you meant that your OS duplicated. Deleting .applesetupdone will also not duplicate macOS.

Answer (score 0):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/324521/371580
This helped me alot.
If you resintalled on existed Mac OS most probably setup assistant will not show up. If this was the problem
Delete .setupassistantdone from recovery terminal search for it and delete it then everything will be okay.
Find more details with steps in this answer