# Accidentally changed my own UID and now I can't run sudo. How can I fix this?

Tags: terminal, user-account

I ran the command `sudo dscl . -change /Users/YourUserName UniqueID 503 1001` while I was logged in as `YourUserName`. If I try to change it back with `sudo dscl . -change /Users/YourUserName UniqueID 1001 503` I get an `eDSPErmissionError`. Any idea how I can change the ID back?

Comment: You may be able to use one of the methods in the answers to ["I don't have administrator account on my mac"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac), but note that some answers are out of date: depending on your Mac model and macOS version, Single-user mode may not be available (so use Recovery mode), and `.AppleSetupDone` may be on a different volume (I've added comments under some answers about this). Also, it might create a new admin acct with the old ID, which would complicate things.

Comment: Actually, you *might* be able to "fix" it just by rebooting.