# I need to retrieve my password to get administrator access back in macOS High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, security, password, administrator

I have a MacBook Pro that I have forgotten my administrator password to. I believe I last logged into it in 2018, so I am still using macOS High Sierra because I can't upgrade without being in the Admin setting.

I have still been able to work some on my Mac because my son helped me set up another user account for myself back then.

I have tried with Apple Assistance in the past when I still had my 3 year coverage Service Plan upon purchase of my Mac, but we could not get in then either.

I need to add a DAW to my computer for making music, as well as, connect my other music producing and recording equipment for which I bought my Mac for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac). From my understand of how this is suppose to work, any new answers should be posted at the original question. From there, the users can vote and the answer with the most votes rises to the top. (Or, an answer can be accepted.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want create a new Administrator on your Mac, you need boot in Recovery Mode. (cmd+r at boot) .
If Filevault is activated, from Disk Utility, you unlock/mount the System Volume giving the password. (right click on the system volume).
You quit disk utility, then on top menu you select Utilities/Terminal
I suppose the System Volume name is "Macintosh HD", the command is :

```
rm /Volumes/"Macintosh HD"/var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

If no error message you reboot the Mac and then you will be invited to create a new administrator.

Then you can modify and repair your initial User admin account.

Comment: @user3439894 Wy do you modify my poste. If you don't agree this make youself an other response. Who are you to do that? I find these cavalier ways and if this continues I will quickly get away from here. OK?

Comment: Jean_JD, The original answer was basically a link-only answer and they are frowned upon here. I copied your answer in the link to here so the OP or anyone else landing here didn't unnecessarily have to go elsewhere.

Comment: @user3439894. 

There may be more constructive things to do than correcting the so-called anomalies. ;-{

Comment: Jean_JD: You posted an answer and this question may stay open or may close. However, you should consider posting an answer at the [original question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac). With 73 votes and 495k views, I would assume your answer get some coverage.