# Changed user account name and now notes gone missing

Tags: notes.app, accounts

I changed the name of my user account which then made a new folder on my computer for this account and I lost important notes which I now can’t or don’t know how to access. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you change the name?

Comment: I just changed it in the users section in system preferences, I might have click on advanced options in there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I don't have administrator account on my mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac)

Comment: Not really the same thing bro

Comment: It would help if you described *exactly* what you changed, as well as what "notes" you're talking about (e.g. are these in the built-in Notes.app, or something else). Also, under the new name, is your acct still recognized as an administrator? And, just in case, do you have a backup?

Comment: So I just went in to the user and groups on the system preferences and pressed advanced options on the user account and changed the username, both accounts are seen as administrator. Yes bro it’s the notes app that comes built in on the mac and no I don’t have a backup man.

Comment: If you execute the terminal command `ls -l /Users/` can you see the old and the new name of your User?

Comment: Yeah bro I see that

Comment: If you execute the command  `dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]'` can you verify that the old "name" under Users is'nt used by any account?

Comment: Yes bro just checked it’s not being used

Comment: That you can do : Create a new User (admin or no) with the exact name "Account Name" present in /Users directory. The system will prompt you if you want use the prresent structure. You say Yes and you can access to your Datas.  When you modify the User Name keep in mind to do this from another Admin Account and veryfy and adapt the /Users/name before you connect to this modify account.

Comment: So do I call it account name? Or I write the name of the account that got deleted?

Comment: You do as you wish, the main thing is that the Account name (not the full name) exactly matches the name on /Users (your old account name).

Answer (score 0):

If you want change your User Name, the good method is detailed here : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548