# the user account changed to standard and become not adminstrate the computer please help

Tags: macos, user-account

On macOS Sierra I was trying to change the settings like profile name and other settings when I clicked on the lock symbol to open this setting to change it. I accidentally clicked on and doesn't allow my user account to administrate the computer and restart the computer, unfortunately. this is what I did. –
the user account changed to standard and when I tried to change the setting again, the computer asked me to enter my username and password, and I entered them but it didn't work although they were correct.

Comment: You changed the admin user to a standard one? Do you have another admin user? If not, which version of macOS are you running, on what hardware?

Comment: Yes, I changed it. No, I didn't have...macOS high sierra

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide more information and not in comments. Editing alows much better formatting so it is much easier to read and so readers won't give up so quickly`

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac

Comment: Aliaa, can you try the methods described in the answers to the two questions linked on top of your post?